# Saving Access Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have the following which opens the SaveAs Dialog box, however it's not actually saving the file when I click save.

```
Dim SaveBox As Object
Set SaveBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With SaveBox
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = "WeeklyLog " & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd")
SaveBox.Show
End With
```

Comment: Are you trying to save as a text file?  Excel spreadsheet?  Word doc?

Comment: As pdf.  I asked it below before refreshing the page and seeing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"... opens the SaveAs Dialog box, however it's not actually saving the file when I click save"*

`FileDialog` can give you a string which contains a file path.  But it does not actually perform a "Save As" operation.  It's up to you, the developer, to use that file path in your code to save something somewhere.

```vb
Dim SaveBox As Object
Dim strFilePath As String

Set SaveBox = Application.FileDialog(2) ' msoFileDialogSaveAs
With SaveBox
    .InitialFileName = "WeeklyLog " & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd")
    If .Show = True Then
        strFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

' now do something with strFilePath ...
If Len(strFilePath) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "File path: " & strFilePath
Else
    MsgBox "Selection cancelled."
End If
```

Comment: Got it, good to know.  I added    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "WeeklyLogReport", acFormatPDF, strFilePath, False and it saves the file just not a a pdf.  Just a file without an extension.

Comment: der...just need to add ".pdf" to .InitialFileName = "WeeklyLog " & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".pdf".  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This will save an Excel file, I think you only need a tiny bit of tweaking to get it to save a PDF:

```
Sub GetFileName()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim fname As String

    Do
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        With fd
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = "New To Do.xls"
            If .Show = -1 Then fname = .SelectedItems(1)

            If fname = fd.InitialFileName Then _
                MsgBox "Please enter a new filename", vbOKOnly, "Filename Needed!"
        End With
    Loop Until fname <> fd.InitialFileName

    If IsEmpty(fname) Or fname = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fname

End Sub
```

Comment: actually jsut needed .InitialFileName = "WeeklyLog " & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") **& ".pdf"**  thanks though